# AWS Free Tier - How to enable root user to access billing information?

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing

I am using AWS Free Tier account and logged in as a root user. When I tried to access the [cost explorer](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cost-management/home), it said:

`The IAM policy for the current user does not allow access to this page. IAM policies need to be enabled in order to access the Billing & Cost Management Console.`

Actually the `IAM user/role access to billing information is activated`.

How to let the root user access the billing information? Please advise.

Comment: Is that account part of an AWS organization? (There's no such thing as a free tier account by the way)

Comment: @Maurice I created an account through https://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: In that case the **root account user** has access to the billing information, it can't be restricted via IAM policies. That tells me you're not using the root account user.

Comment: @Maurice I have logged in as root user and I see the error message above

Comment: Root user has full permission. I think It's not the root account. If it's an IAM account, you can add Billing policy.

Comment: @Maurice Even I created an IAM user and gave that user AdministratorAccess (AWS managed policy) but still I am not able to access Cost Explorer page

Comment: The root account user can enable IAM users to get access to the cost explorer, this is a one-time-configuration, that can only be done by the root account user. I don't know what to tell you, the error message indicates you're not the root account user and you claim you are. Either AWS is fundamentally broken or there is a misunderstanding, I tend to think it's the latter :-)

Comment: You did [enable cost explorer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/ce-enable.html) right?

Comment: @Maurice I activated [IAM access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/control-access-billing.html#grantaccess)

Comment: @Maurice //The root account user can enable IAM users to get access to the cost explorer, this is a one-time-configuration, that can only be done by the root account user.// Yes, I did this one time config as a root user. After that, I am not able to access Cost Explorer either as a root user or as an IAM user

Comment: @Maurice //On the Welcome to Cost Explorer page, choose Launch Cost Explorer.// It is at this step I get the message `The IAM policy for the current user does not allow access to this page. IAM policies need to be enabled in order to access the Billing & Cost Management Console`

Comment: @Maurice After I created an organization and linked my account to it, I was able to access Cost Explorer almost after half an hour. Thank you.